# Unable to sign apk using calabash

Tags: android, sign, calabash-android

I am unable to sign my apk using calabash I get the following error when i try to sign/run my apk using calabash, i tried signing it using eclipse and then running it but no luck there as well.

This is the verbose output when i do calabash-android resign Android.apk

```
2014-07-27 19:30:43 - JDK found on PATH.
2014-07-27 19:30:43 - JDK found at: C:\java
2014-07-27 19:30:43 - Android SDK found at: C:\Android
2014-07-27 19:30:43 - Resign apk
2014-07-27 19:30:43 - "\java\bin/keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -
eystore C:/Users/sripathi/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android "-J"-Dfile
encoding=utf-8""
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Key store data:
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: 27 Jul, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 13cf4c92
Valid from: Sun Jul 27 18:49:03 CEST 2014 until: Sat Oct 25 18:49:03 CEST 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  07:47:FA:22:76:65:6B:58:EB:07:99:93:69:43:E0:61
         SHA1: FA:5E:63:58:AE:EE:42:77:50:D7:2E:25:8D:73:9A:2B:97:83:59:DE
         SHA256: 24:3F:BB:C5:0A:03:0D:6F:79:F7:3F:BB:C8:29:74:70:8F:6F:90:E5:8E
46:B9:E6:EF:DC:3A:19:12:64:FC:2C
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 2D 9C 41 90 46 E8 C6 24   97 44 4C 29 0A A3 12 FF  -.A.F..$.DL)....
0010: 32 C2 42 B8                                        2.B.
]
]

2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Unlocked keystore at C:/Users/sripathi/.android/debug.key
tore - fingerprint: 07:47:FA:22:76:65:6B:58:EB:07:99:93:69:43:E0:61
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/calabash/debug.keystore
 no such file
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Users/sripathi/.local/sh
re/Xamarin/Mono/ for/ Android/debug.keystore - no such file
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - Trying to read keystore from: C:/Users/sripathi/AppData/L
cal/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore - no such file
2014-07-27 19:30:44 - "\java\bin/jarsigner.exe" -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg S
A1 -signedjar C:/Users/sripathi/AppData/Local/Temp/d20140727-9424-19ca9d3/unali
ned.apk -storepass android -keystore C:/Users/sripathi/.android/debug.keystore
:/Users/sripathi/AppData/Local/Temp/d20140727-9424-19ca9d3/unsigned.apk android
ebugkey
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.1/lib/calabash-android
java_keystore.rb:27:in `sign_apk': Could not sign app: C:/Users/sripathi/AppDat
/Local/Temp/d20140727-9424-19ca9d3/unsigned.apk (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.1/lib/cal
bash-android/helpers.rb:77:in `sign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.1/lib/cal
bash-android/helpers.rb:57:in `block in resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.1/lib/cal
bash-android/helpers.rb:51:in `resign_apk'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.1/bin/cal
bash-android:114:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting my .android folder on my machine and recreating the  keystore and it works now .

Comment: how to recreate keystore?